# Getting error in Hartl's tutorial running "bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm learning Ruby from Michael Hartl's tutorial. I'm following the steps one by one, but I can't get passed this one. When I input "bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb" I get a very long error response as opposed to a simple "1 example, 0 failures". I changed the necessary code in the static pages directories and I'm fairly confident the code is correct as I simply copied and pasted. The error message is this:

```
/Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `require': dlopen(/Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/marlon/.bundler/tmp/1219/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Reason: Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0 - /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/marlon/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marlon/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/marlon/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marlon/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/marlon/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marlon/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/marlon/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
dyn172-30-28-254:sample_app marlon$
```

Please let me know what I can do to fix this. I appreciate all the help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install nokogiri dependencies:

```
brew install libxml2 --with-xml2-config
brew install libxslt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get this when I try that: "sudo: apt-get: command not found"

Comment: I use OS X Mountain Lion on a Retina MacBook Pro.

Comment: I updated the answer. I don't know OS X, but it should do, I think.

Comment: Hey, thanks again. I get "Warning: libxml2-2.9.1 already installed" and "Warning: libxslt-1.1.28 already installed"

Comment: What is the output of `brew --prefix libxml2`?

Comment: The output is: "/usr/local/opt/libxml2"

One thing I just tried is running is "bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb" but in the "app" subdirectory. The output is shorter but still an error. Are you supposed to run the command there however?

Comment: I found this:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/What-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk
I think it can help

Comment: Thanks, but I really can't follow the instructions. Also, it says "Everything below this line on this page is severely out-of-date and should not be expected to help you, at all.". Any other idea haha :(?

Comment: Okay, I got it working somehow. I just had to reinstall Capybara for some reason!